# PyCharm fails to install Packages

Tags: python, python-3.x

Package installs are currently failing no matter what I do. I've checked the file permissions, and they were set to read/write so I'm not sure why this directory is not owned by the current user. I've also ran `sudo chown -R $USERNAME /Users/$USERNAME/Library/Caches/pip` to no avail. I'm guessing this is due to improper use of Sudo? I realize I can install these packages using Sudo through the command line, but I don't want to have to do that each and every time. Thanks!

> 40:461: execution error: The directory
>   '/Users/stevennguyen/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory
>   is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.
>   Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing
>   pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

[Detailed Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvVhm.png)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that you may not own one of the directories above there and it doesn't like that.  I would run `sudo chown -R stevennguyen /Users/stevennguyen` to ensure that *everything* in your home directory is owned by you.  This usually does happen with improper sudo use, such as running `sudo pip install`.  If you want to run pip with root privileges to install a package system wide, you should do as it suggests and run `sudo -H pip install` so that the ownership of files in your pip directories do not change.  I have noticed that this is a particular issue on Mac especially, though it does happen on other *nix systems as well.